# SyncDown Configuration (usersyncs.json) with dynamic filter

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

If I want to dynamically set a filter to my SOQL in the `usersyncs.json` definition (see below, what to sync down only the contacts that I own), what is the best way for doing this? I know I can add a sync via code, but prefer doing this via config. Would a possible solution is to set this initial config first, and I change the SOQL in code in run time?

```
{
  "syncs": [
    {
      "syncName": "syncDownContacts",
      "syncType": "syncDown",
      "soupName": "contacts",
      "target": {"type":"soql", "query":"SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE **OwnerId = XXXX**"},
      "options": {"mergeMode":"OVERWRITE"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The soql of the SoqlSyncDownTarget cannot be changed (otherwise the meaning of doing a re sync or a clean sync ghosts would be hard to define).

If you need to dynamically change the filter, you should define a new sync (programmatically).